# Maven archetype not using properties to create module names

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I created an archetype where you can set the moduleName (or expect to) using
a required property moduleName, here is the archetype metadata xml (reduced, which I also tried with similar results)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor name="modules-archetype">

  <requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="moduleName">
    </requiredProperty>
  </requiredProperties>

  <modules>
    <module id="modules-${moduleName}-api" 
            dir="modules-__moduleName__-api" 
            name="modules-${moduleName}-api">
      <fileSets>
        <fileSet encoding="UTF-8">
          <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </fileSet>
      </fileSets>
    </module>
  </modules>

</archetype-descriptor>
```

After installing and generating, the moduleName value is not used in the
directory name or the artifactid, the resuting values are

```
For the directory:        project/module-__moduleName__-api
For the pom/artifactId:   module-${moduleName}-api
```

The value is replaced correctly on some other files of the project, so
no spelling problems I guess.

I've seen a lot of similar things, but all of them using rootArtifactId, and in fact
if I use rootArtifactId (as the starting part of the name) it works as expected.

Not able to find a similar problem around, any idea why is it not working, or how to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

I found a reasonable work-around.

Seems the only place where you can only use the **rootArtifactId** is the
**`<module>`** element in the **archetype descriptor**, but in every other
place you can use the **moduleName** property without any trouble.

What I did:

Use **${moduleName}** in

- artifactId in module's pom
- some default dependencies
- The module definition in the main pom 
  `(<module>module-${moduleName}</module>)`
- etc.

Use  **__*moduleName*__** in

- package name in src/main/java & resources

In the **artifact descriptor**

- Use a fix module name something like 
  module-sample1 & module-sample2
  (and of course name the directories inside
  the artifact resources the same way).

**Things to fix** after the project is created

1. The modules' directory name
2. Take out the module elements in the main pom
   that contains module-sample[12]

All of this in a ant script embedded in a postcreate-pom.xml
to be run after project creation.

And it worked smoothly.

Hope its useful for someone.

thanks to everybody that just take the time to read my
question, tonio.

Comment: I have the same problem. What do you mean with 'postcreate-pom.xml'? Is there a standard way to do some post-create-action at the end of a project creation?

Comment: Well I didn't find a way to do so, I just create the postcreate-pom.xml as part of the project and run it afterwards to complete the project setup.

Comment: The correct approach is the one by @sgpalit (even though not straight forward)

Answer (score 4):

archetype-metadata.xml and the pom.xml of the sub-module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor name="multi-module">

  <modules>
    <module name="${rootArtifactId}-ria" id="${rootArtifactId}-ria" dir="__rootArtifactId__-ria">
      <fileSets>
        <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
          <directory>src/main/java</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.java</include>
          </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
            <includes>
                <include>pom.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
      </fileSets>
    </module>
  </modules>


</archetype-descriptor>
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${rootArtifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

</project>
```

Update for directory structure:
[image: archetype]

Comment: Yo saved my day! Thank you

Comment: Even though this is the correct answer it would be worth to elaborate. Show the directory structure in archetype-resources at least because it's very much not straight forward

Answer (score 2):

Looking inside maven-archetype sources (version 2.2), seems the only possible value to use is rootArtifactId extracted from DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator

```java
   while (subprojects.hasNext() ) {

        ModuleDescriptor project = subprojects.next();

        File moduleOutputDirectoryFile = new File( outputDirectoryFile
             , StringUtils.replace( project.getDir()
                   , "__rootArtifactId__"
                   , rootArtifactId 
                   ));
        ...........
```

Comment: See bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-191 which does not clarify things to much, but at least the problem is already around

Answer (score 1):

After generating the archetype from a project, edit the file `target\generated-sources\archetype\src\main\resources\META-INF\maven\archetype-metadata.xml`.

Add

```
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory></directory>
      <includes>
        <include>pom.xml</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
```

This will make it filter your pom file!  Then run `mvn install` again.

Comment: The problem I had was that I tried to use ${artifactId} in one of the config .yml file and it didn't work. Going into the archetype-metadata.xml and include */**.yml works.  Thanks