# Is it possible to give dynamic directory structure in customized maven archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I have created a new maven archetype so that it will generate my customized project structure. For that I have created a project with archetype-metadata.xml and pom.xml to be generated.

Under META-INF/maven I have archetype-metadata.xml file-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <archetype-descriptor xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd" name="test"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <fileSets>
            <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
              <directory>com/test/MyProject</directory>
              <includes>
                 <include>.classpath</include>
                 <include>.project</include>
              </includes>
           </fileSet>
          </fileSets>
       </archetype-descriptor>
```

and archetype-resources/pom.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

This is working as expected and I am able to create a new maven project using this archetype.
Now I want to create a dynamic directory structue. As in , I want to create a directory named  ${artifactId} in fileset. i.e. somewhat like -

```
 <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
     <directory>com/test/${artifactId}</directory>
      <includes>
         <include>.classpath</include>
          <include>.project</include>
      </includes>
  </fileSet>
```

I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419659/5198430) , but I am not able to achieve it.

Is it possible to give such dynamic directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems it was a bug which should already be fixed since some years. probably now the bug occurs again?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-191

see also [Maven archetype not using properties to create module names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830002/maven-archetype-not-using-properties-to-create-module-names) with some discussions on workarounds.